# Push Notification, Reminder Calendar, EventKit implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, eventkit, reminders

I have a TableViewController app in Xcode and I would like to add a remember calendar, a push notification functionality and alarms like the built-in Reminders app. Could you help me with the implementation and five me some tips? 
I hope you could help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement EventKit the tutorial of Ray Wenderlich might be a starting point http://www.raywenderlich.com/64513/cookbook-making-calendar-reminder